# javascript show hide - handling html elements inside text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am showing and hiding text with js - with buttons `more` and `less`

```
var showChar = 330;
var ellipsestext = '...';
var moretext  = "more";
var content = $('#content').html();            
if(content.length > showChar) {             
   var c = content.substr(0, showChar-1);
   var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);             
   var html = c + '<span class="more">' + ellipsestext + '</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';             
   $('#content').html(html);
} 
$(".morelink").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
     $(this).removeClass("less");
     $(this).html(moretext);
  } else {
     $(this).addClass("less");
     $(this).html(lesstext);
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
  $(this).prev().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

the problem i am having is: if the content can have sometimes
`<strong class="yellow">text</strong>` and 330th char is somewhere in the middle of this strong element, it is cutting and the rest of the whole content is becoming yellow.

how can I detect if more-less is going to cut html element and avoid this html destroying?

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vvf8d/

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle with an example of what you're trying to accomplish? There's probably a better way of accomplishing want you're trying to do, rather then mess with .html()

Comment: @Kolby i added the fiddle

Comment: And can you explain better what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Kolby dude, read the last part of my question

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use `$('#content').text()` instead of `$('#content').html()`

Comment: then, it removes all ``<strong>text</strong>`` and replaces with normal ``text``.

Comment: does this tool handle this html element also?